# Llenar Array con numeros aleatorios

Tags: java, array, busqueda

tengo el siguiente codigo que me busca dentro de una tabla si el numero pasado por teclado está dentro de la misma:

```
import java.util.*;

public class busquedaSecuencial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int[] numeros = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; 
        int n, i = 0; 
        boolean encontrado = false; 

        System.out.println("\tPrograma que busque un numero en una lista");
        
        System.out.print("Introduce el numero que deseas buscar: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("\n");

        while ((i < numeros.length) && !encontrado) {
            if (numeros[i++] == n) {
                encontrado = true;
            }
        }
        
        if (encontrado) {
            System.out.println("El número " + n + " está en la lista");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El numero " + n + " no está en la lista\n");
        }
    }
}
```

La cuestión es que me gustaria que la tabla se rellenase automaticamente con valores aleatorios.
Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Crea un bucle for donde saques un número random en cada iteración y lo añades a la lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
int valor;    
for(byte a = 0; a < numeros.length; a++) {            
     valor = rand.NextInt(100);     
     numeros[a] = valor;        
}
```

De esta manera rellenarías al azar las posiciones del array con números del 0 al 100. Pruebalo a ver que tal te va.